# Pygame Joystick - No data from from Joystick

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, hid

I am trying to test if a button is pressed down on my Logitech F310 Gamepad. I am on xubuntu 13.10 and am running Python 3.3.2.

When I run the code below, I get nothing. The program just waits, and prints nothing, not even zeroes. I have tried pressing all the buttons but nothing happens. Any tips or advice?

The code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
gamepad = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
gamepad.init()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Button Pressed.")
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: what does print(gamepad) print?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski It prints '<Joystick object at 0xb5bd4b60>'

Comment: What about print(gamepad.get_name())?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski It prints 'Logitech Logitech Dual Action'. I have it in 'D-input' mode if that helps.

Comment: Well than it looks like it has found the joystick. Do any other event pop up? (`JOYAXISMOTION` `JOYBALLMOTION` `JOYBUTTONDOWN` `JOYBUTTONUP` `JOYHATMOTION`)

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Nothing at all. The loop just keeps terminating over and over and nothing happens. Is there another test I can do to debug it?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski One more thing: When I print 'pygame.event.get()' in the while loop, it constantly returns empty lists. Is my joystick configured incorrectly? No events are taking place, even when I move the joysticks and press the buttons.

Comment: how about this `print (pygame.event.get_blocked())` and `print(pygame.event.get_grab())`

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Both get_blocked(pygame.JOYBUTTON) and get_grab() return 0 when called in the while loop.